# return type of hql query

Tags: java, authentication, hql

I have a function to check validity of a user as follows :

```
public boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {

    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        String hql = "FROM LoginC L where L.userName=:uname and L.password=:pwd";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("uname", username).setParameter("pwd", password);

//I am not sure how to proceed/check here?
        List<LoginC> result = null;
        result = query.list();
        if (null != result) {
            validUser = true;
        } else {
            validUser = false;
        }

    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        System.out.println("error authenticating "+username+" "+he.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return validUser;
}
```

I am not so expert on HQL and hence don't know what the query will return and how can I test it. Even on entering username-password, not existing in DB it returns `true`. I am even not sure if hql query is correct.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 if (null != result && result.size() != 0) {

 }
```